# Si dentro de una función creo un "for" que a su vez tiene dentro un "if" y en ese "if" creo una variable, ¿No puedo usar la variable fuera del for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código de una tarea y no he podido avanzar de esta parte. Creé una función y dentro de la función tengo un ciclo for y este a su vez tiene dentro un if en el que defino una variable, pero luego, fuera ya del for, necesito que otro if tome la información de la varible dentro del if del for, pero me dice que no está definida.

Mi función debería crear en una lista 4 números de una cifra diferentes entre sí.

```
    import random as rm
    def clave():
        c = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        pos = 1
        c[0] = rm.randint(0, 9)
    
        while pos<4:
            num = rm.randint(0,9)
            for i in range(0, pos-1):
                if num == c[i]:
                    v = 1
            if v == 0: # -NameError: name 'v' is not defined
                c[pos] = num
                pos = pos+1
            else:
                v = 0
    
    
        return(c)
    
    print(clave())
```

Comment: Tu variable no va a existir a menos de que el if dentro de tu for de verdadero. Cuando ese if da verdadero, se crea por primera vez la variable. El nameeerror que vez es por que tu if nunca da verdadero y por lo tanto tu variable nunca se crea.

Comment: Creo que ya han respondido a tu pregunta en concreto. Tan sólo decirte que lo que quieres programar ya lo tienes hecho en el módulo `random`: `random.sample(range(0,9), 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Esto se resuelve  con tal solo definir la variable antes del for.

```
import random as rm

def clave():
    c = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    pos = 1
    c[0] = rm.randint(0, 9)
    v = 6   ### LINEA NUEVA
    while pos<4:
        num = rm.randint(0,9)

        for i in range(0, pos-1):
            if num == c[i]:
                v = 1
        if v == 0: # -NameError: name 'v' is not defined
            c[pos] = num
            pos = pos+1
        else:
            v = 0


    return(c)

print(clave())
```

El valor inicial de v es arbitrario pero ten en cuenta que debe tener un valor distinto a evaluado en tu ciclo para que no genere resultados no deseados mientras que no se active la condicional del for